# How can I get P4CLIENT

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, command-line-interface, perforce

I want to be able to reference the P4CLIENT perforce environment variable when writing in the command line. For instance:

```
echo P4CLIENT
```

Or something like this to return the current client name only. I know this is a variable that perforce has stored but I can't figure out how to access it.

This feels like it should be simple and is probably something wrong with my knowledge of CLI rather than perforce.

Thanks for any help!

[Windows server 2019 - 64bit, Perforce v2020.1]

Comment: `p4 set P4CLIENT`, or `p4 -Ztag -F %clientName% info`

Comment: @Samwise Excellent the Ztag -F did the job as that returns just the string of the client name. Thanks!